# Seeding a database

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, database

I'm seeding [my database](https://editor.ponyorm.com/user/nemolinero/Ask_Dima) with a relatively complex data model.

Constraints: Every meal has exactly one main dish (marked as `is_main` in intermediate table).

Here is my `seeds.rb` file:

```
User.create!(name:  "User", #create normal user
             surname: "Name",
             email: "someemail@example.org",
             password:              "11111111",
             password_confirmation: "11111111",
             zip: 188661)

5.times do |n| #create remaining users
    name = Faker::Name.first_name
    surname = Faker::Name.last_name
    email = Faker::Internet.safe_email
    password="11111111"
    password_confirmation="11111111"
    zip=Faker::Number.between(111111, 999999)
    address=Faker::Address.street_address
    room=Faker::Number.between(1, 1000)
    telephone=Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone

    User.create!(
        name: name,
        surname: surname,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        password_confirmation: password_confirmation,
        zip: zip,
        address: address,
        room: room,
        telephone: telephone)
end

User.ids.each do |n| #create cook profile for all users
    about=Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(2)
    about_kitchen=Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(1)
    how_to_find = Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(1)

    CookProfile.create!(
        about: about,
        about_kitchen: about_kitchen,
        how_to_find: how_to_find,
        user_id: n) 
end


30.times do |n| #create 30 different dishes 
    name = Faker::Company.buzzword
    description = Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(1)
    price = Faker::Number.between(3000, 20000)
    cook_profile_id = CookProfile.ids[Faker::Number.between(0, CookProfile.count-1)]

    Dish.create!(
             cook_profile_id: cook_profile_id,
             name: name,
             description: description,
             price: price)
end


8.times do |n|  
    date_ready  = Faker::Date.forward(10)
    hours_before_stopping_orders = Faker::Number.between(2, 5)
    is_free_delivery = Faker::Boolean.boolean
    time_before_take_away = Faker::Time.between(2.days.ago, Time.now, :day)
    time_ready = Faker::Time.between(2.days.ago, Time.now, :day)

    Meal.create!(
             is_publish: true,
             date_ready: date_ready,
             hours_before_stopping_orders: hours_before_stopping_orders,
             is_free_delivery: is_free_delivery,
             time_before_take_away: time_before_take_away,
             time_ready: time_ready)
end


p=Array.new #one meal contain exactly one main dish
cook_ids=Array.new 
Dish.all.each do |n|
    meal_id=Meal.ids[Faker::Number.between(0, Meal.count-1)]
    if cook_ids.include? n.cook_profile_id
        pp=MealDishConnection.joins(:dish).where({dishes: {cook_profile_id: n.cook_profile_id}}).select(:meal_id)
        meal_id=pp[Faker::Number.between(0, pp.count-1)].meal_id
    else
        cook_ids<<n.cook_profile_id 
        result=Meal.ids-p
        meal_id=result.shuffle.first
    end


    if p.include? meal_id

                MealDishConnection.create!(
                     dish_id: n.id,
                     max_amount_of_dishes: 5,
                     meal_id: meal_id,
                     is_main:false)
    else
                p<<meal_id
                MealDishConnection.create!(
                     dish_id: n.id,
                     max_amount_of_dishes: 5,
                     meal_id: meal_id,
                     is_main:true)
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) to accomplish this.  To give you some ideas:

*User Factory*

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    surname { Faker::Name.last_name }
    email { "#{first_name}.#{last_name}@#{Faker::Internet.domain_name}".downcase }
    password { Faker::Lorem.word }
    password_confirmation { "#{password}" }
    zip { Faker::Number.between(111111, 999999) }
    # ... assign other attributes

    factory :john do
      name 'John'
      surname 'Smith'
      email 'johnsmith@example.org'
      password '11111111'
      password_confirmation '11111111'
      zip '188661'
    end

    factory :user_with_cook_profile_and_dishes do
      after(:create) do |user|
        create(:cook_profile_with_dishes, user: user)
      end
    end

  end
end
```

*Profile Factory*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :cook_profile do
    about { Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(2) }
    about_kitchen {Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(1) }
    how_to_find { Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(1) }

    factory :cook_profile_with_dishes do
      after(:create) do |cook_profile|
        (1..5).times do
          meal = create(:meal_with_main_dish)
          main_dish = meal.main_dish # You'll have to implement something that can get the main dish from a meal
          main_dish.cook_profile = self
        end
      end
    end

  end
end
```

*Dish Factory*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :dish do
    name { Faker::Company.buzzword }
    #... assign rest of attributes
  end
end
```

*Meal Factory*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :meal do
    date_ready { Faker::Date.forward(10) }
    # ... assign rest of attributes (description, price )

    factory :meal_with_main_dish do
      after(:create) do |meal|
        create(:dish, meal: meal)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then, your `seeds.rb` file could simply become:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:john)
30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_cook_profile_and_dishes) }
```